# Objective programming approach in particural situation

Tags: vb.net

Would like to get your advice. Let's assume i have some particular code which depends on some number then accordingly some steps has to be done differently. Let's take above examples. In my program user has to choose about something, and by this decision i am showing him either one, two or three listboxes with values. Then between them he making connections (between items). I keep that information in object called "VariationsEnum". Therefore i have some code where depends on it i have to use either based on one, two or three. So in almost all of my code i have to check what was the decision. Let's take this two peaces of code as an example. As you see i always has to use select case to check enum because based on that i know how to prepare objects. So what's not good i am bit duplicating code and i don't know how to do it diffrent way. Is there something else which could be done to improve my code?

**example:**

```
Case VariationsEnum.One    
  If row.Cells(1).Value.ToString = variationswert1("Name").ToString & romanNumber Then
  End If

Case VariationsEnum.Two     
  Dim variationswert2 As DataRowView = lbVar2.SelectedItem

  If row.Cells(1).Value.ToString = variationswert1("Name").ToString & romanNumber And row.Cells(3).Value.ToString = variationswert2("Name").ToString & romanNumber Then
     End If

Case VariationsEnum.Three  
    Dim variationswert2 As DataRowView = lbVar2.SelectedItem
    Dim variationswert3 As DataRowView = lbVar3.SelectedItem

    If row.Cells(1).Value.ToString = variationswert1("Name").ToString & romanNumber And row.Cells(3).Value.ToString = variationswert2("Name").ToString & romanNumber And row.Cells(5).Value.ToString = variationswert3("Name").ToString & romanNumber Then
    End If
End Select
```

Comment: I would like to give you advice. Let's assume I have some solution code which depends on some number, then accordingly some proper steps has to be done correctly. Then you can improve your code.

Comment: I provided example. Simply saying is every in my code i have to check mentioned enum and based on that i am doing operations like if row.Cells... so same thing everywhere diffrent parameters number. How to improve that?